# Solve multivariable limit

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{x^3 + y^4}{x^2 + y^2}$$

I am almost sure it is equal to $0$ but I can't prove it.
Please give me some hint.

Comment: Use polar coordinates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this inequality

$$0\le\left|\frac{x^3 + y^4}{x^2 + y^2}\right|\le\frac{|x|x^2 + |y|^2|y|^2}{x^2 + y^2}\le|x|+|y|^2\xrightarrow{(x,y)\to(0,0)}0$$

Comment: How do you have the last inequality?

Comment: We have 
$$|x|x^2+|y|^2|y|^2\le (|x|+|y|^2)(x^2+y^2)$$

Comment: Ah thanks! Cheers to a great simple answer!

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score -1):

A more Rigerous solution one could show, which would be expected in Real Analysis.

If the multivariate limit F(x,y) -> 0 for x and y approaching 0 ,then it must be true that {Xn} -> 0 and {Yn} -> 0 so that F({Xn}, {Yn}) -> 0 for all such sequences {Xn}, {Yn} that approach 0.  Examples of single variable sequences that approach 0 are {1/n}, {1/n^2}, etc. as n approaches infinity.

In other words if there exist two sequences that both approach 0 as n goes to infinity such that F({Xn}, {Yn}) = 0, but then there exists other sequences (one is sufficient) such that F({Xn}, {Yn}) = L where L is not equal to 0.  Then F must be divergent, because it is impossible for a converging sequence to have more than one limit point.

Let us have {Xn} = {1/n} and {Yn} = {1/n}, this implies

F({Xn}, {Yn}) =  F({1/n}, {1/n}) = lim n -> infinity ( (n+1)/2n^2 ) -> 0

So it was shown for two sequences, it would get very tiring to show all sequences approach 0.  The trick would be to assume that for two sequences approaching 0, that F({Xn}, {Yn}) -> L not equal to 0, and then show a contradiction arises if you do so.  By contradiction assume  there are two sequences that both approach 0 such that {Xn} -> 0 and {Ym} = {0} -> 0 for n and m approaching infinity.  (Yes {Ym} is constant), and

F({Xn}, {Ym}) = L not equal to 0, which implies

lim n, m -> infinity ( ({Xn}^3 + 0) / ({Xn}^2 + 0) ) = lim n,m -> infinity ( {Xn} ) = L not equal to 0.  But we asserted that {Xn} -> 0, so a contradiction has arisen.  This must mean that F({Xn}, {Ym}) -> 0.

Q.E.D.

Comment: This doesn't really make much sense...and it doesn't really help to answer the question.

Comment: First, The author of the question said "give a hint" not the answer.  Anyone who has studied Real Analysis can make perfect sense of it.  If Any two sequences approaching 0 in this particular instance

Comment: Well @Gary, if you think you know better than someone you don't even know (that's it, me), please do go on...

Comment: Sorry, I was not being condescending, but in the comment I hit the 5 minute limit, and could not post the rest.  So, I edited the answer and hopefully it makes more sense.

Comment: It really doesn't, @Gary. You think you've proved that $\;x_n\rightarrow 0\;,\;\;y_n=0\implies F(x_n,y_n)\to L\neq 0\;$ gives you a contradiction (I say "you think" since I can't quite understand what you wrote without using MathJax...), but even if it does this **only** proves that *if the limit exists* then it must be zero....what if $\;\lim F(x_n,y_n)\;$ doesn't even exist to begin with? Your supposed proof doesn't address this case...Your sticking to the definition "$\;\lim F(x)\;$ exists iff $\;\lim F(x_n)\;$ exists for all sequences...etc." is not very easy **at all** to work with.

Comment: To use MathJax to write mathematics in this site and **greatly** improve the presentation of your posts take a peek at http://meta.matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/93/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: If F(x,y) is continuous, then it must be limit preserving so that F(x,y) = G(x,y)/H(x,y) which implies F(x,y) is continuous and limit preserving where H(x,y) != 0.  It is in general true that if {Xn} -> L, then it must be true that {F({Xn})} -> F(L), that is if F is continous.

Comment: Also, I am looking into Math Jax and LaTex.